# Instanceof returns false for same class after serialization

Tags: java, spring, class, serialization, classloader

Instanceof returns false for same class after org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.util.SerializationUtils fasterxml deserialization in Spring boot application

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(serialized, User.class);
```

Class

```
public class User implements Serializable {//...
}
```

Because new object getClass().getClassloader() returns different classloader, how to fix this and **casting** issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This same issue happened to me once. It was related to spring dev tools. Once I got rid of that dependency, everything worked as expected. If you have that dependency, try removing or check if there is any dependency creating this issue.

Comment: As Alain Said removing dependency below worked for me.                                                           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should compare the class names rather then using `instanceof`. Even if the classes are loaded by different class loaders the canonical names will be the same:

```
public boolean haveSameCanonicalName(Object object, Class<?> clazz) {
     String actualClassName = object.getClass().getCanonicalName();
     String expectedClassName = clazz.getCanonicalName();
     return actualClassName.equals(expectedClassName);
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
if (haveSameCanonicalName(user, User.class)) {
    // Do something here
}
```

UPDATE:

If you still need to cast the object there is a workaround:

```
 public class CrossCastUtils {

    private final ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private final ObjectInputStream ois;

    public CrossCastUtils() throws IOException {
        final PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
        final PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(pos);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(pis);
    }

    public <T> T cast(Object object) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.flush();
        return (T) ois.readObject();
    }
```

Try to run this test:

```
@Test
public void testCrossCast(){
    Object initial = ... // retrieve it as you did before
    User result = CrossCastUtils.cast(initial);

    assertFalse(initial instanceof User);
    assertTrue(result instanceof User);
}
```

Comment: @ArthurDn I updated my answer (added cross-casting workaround)